# Committing Data in a Loop

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am processing files in a loop like this pseudo code:

```
foreach (filename in files) {
    database("insert into file_processed(filename) values (@filename)")
    database("delete from file_staging")
    foreach (line in filename) {
        database("insert into filestaging(column, list) values (@line.split()")
    }
    database("merge filestaging into filepermanent")
    database("commit");
}
```

The problem is: as soon as I do the commit() the insert at the top of the loop fails because the commit terminated the transaction.

**Is there a way to do a commit() without terminating the transaction?**

Note: I am pretty sure the answer that is no, but I would be very happy to be surprised.

**Is there a way to associate a new transaction with an existing SqlCommand?**

The context of that question is that currently I only see a way to associated a transaction on a `New SqlCommand(...)`.  That seems like a waste to keep running that in a loop with all the other overhead of setting the parameters.

```
    public void InsertRunHistory(string datasource, DateTime rundate)
    {
        SqlCommand command = InsertIVS_RUNHISTORY;

        command.SetTransaction(transaction);  // Does this exist?
        command.Parameters[0].Value = datasource;
        command.Parameters[1].Value = rundate;
        command.Parameters[2].Value = r_activity_id;

        ivs_runhistory_id = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
```

Comment: `Is there a way to associate a new transaction with an existing SqlCommand?` I would suggest creating a new command **and** transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the magic command....
This line of code from my sample:

```
command.SetTransaction(transaction);
```

was replaced with this:

```
command.Transaction = transaction;
```

That is, it is set by its property on the SqlCommand object.

In my actual code I am not setting in the same method as the Execute, I am doing it on the top of the loop.

There is no need to create a new SqlCommand because it is possible to assign a new SqlTransaction to the existing SqlCommand.